# Recover FOSUserbundle's password in clear

Tags: symfony-3.4

I would like to know how to recover the password decrypted FOSUserbundle because with

$user->getPassword()

, it sends me the password encrypted

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why would you access plain text passwords ?

Comment: the administrator creates the accounts and he has the full controle about them, thats why he needs to recover the user's informations, and in this case the password is encrypted, i don't know what to do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Once the password has been saved, you will NOT be able to see the decrypted version. FOSUserBundle only stores the encrypted version by default.

If your workflow requires you to be able to see the decrypted password, you could do this by implementing a custom password encryption method - but please don't. Instead, please consider an alternative workflow that does not require this. Your users will thank you.

Comment: the administrator creates the accounts and he has the full controle about them, thats why he needs to  recover the user's 
 informations, and in this case the password is encrypted, i don't know what to do to solve this problem

Comment: Personally, I'd implement either an invitation system (so that the user can set their own password on first login), or a password reset system (so that the user can set a new password). I _think_ FOSUserBundle supports both, but I removed it from my app so I can't confirm. Storing the passwords in a format that can be decrypted is an option, but would require a lot of custom work and is *inherently* dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Password are hashed (not crypted) and this is one way (you can't *unhash*)

---

Being able to get the password as plain text is a potential security breach. If your users are from European Union, (This is maybe the case, your initial post was in french), you may get a 10 millions € fine (GPRD)

If you want to recover passwords with some admin tools, you may want to consider a form that will allow an admin to **change the password instead of getting it as plain text** with at least 3 fields, such as `user_id`, `new_password` and `new_password_verification`, but this is actually too broad to be answered and detailled